# node.js HTTP request using network interface

Tags: node.js, request

I have several network interfaces with various IP adresses. How can I make http requests to site through these IPs using node.js module **request** (https://github.com/mikeal/request) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the nodejs `http` module, there is a `localAddress` option you can use with [`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

> `localAddress`: Local interface to bind for network connections.

I have not used the module you're referring, but if it's just passing through the options to the `http` module, I don't see a reason it shouldn't work.